# Any opensource tools to create and run automated tests on real device (Windows Phone)

Tags: automation, seetest

I want to create and run automation tests and run it on real Windows Phone device. The only tool that i found and it works with real devices is SeeTest. Does anybody knows some alternative tools to do it ?

Comment: If you just want to automate web sites on windows phone, have a look at this: https://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest in currently the only tool Supporting This.